# Where can you find UK marriage records post 2005?

Tags: united-kingdom, records, marriage

Trying to trace descendants of soldiers who fought with my father in Burma in WW2 and need to find marriage records for granddaughters of one such soldier but can only find marriage records up to 2005.

How can I trace these ladies?

Comment: For marriage records in England and Wales pertaining to people who were born less than 100 years ago, some information is likely to be redacted. See Table B, "Information currently in the register where access will be restricted where the individual is under 100 years of age" in this document.   https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/250928/5355.pdf You won't be able to get the address at the time of marriage, the rank of profession of the parties or their father, etc.

Comment: @JanMurphy - I believe that linked paper has gone nowhere and there is currently no redaction on any paper (or paper image) certificates. There is a looming change for marriage records to get mother's names on, which will computerise the marriage certificates, but I have no idea if there is any redaction proposed - it never occurred to me to check. This refers to England and Wales only.

Comment: @AdrianB38 Thanks, I hadn't realized that was only a proposal.  In the US, we often have strict privacy rules for recent certificates. We are likely to run up against 50, 75, or 100 year rules where third-party researchers can't get access.

Comment: when will the information from 2005 be inputted onto the historical sites?

Answer (score 4):

For England and Wales, there are indexes of marriages from the General Register Office extending up to very recently (I believe updated quarterly). However, they are not available online at this time. The complete indexes can be found at [seven locations in England and Wales](https://www.gov.uk/research-family-history), where you can search them for free:

- the Library of Birmingham
- Bridgend Local and Family History Centre
- the City of Westminster Archives Centre
- Manchester Central Library
- Newcastle City Library
- Plymouth Central Library
- The British Library

If you are not able to access these locations, you may consider hiring a genealogist to search for you.

The marriage certificate may be ordered on the [GRO website](https://www.gro.gov.uk) if you have the index reference, or if you know the date and place of marriage.

Alternatively, if you know the location of marriage and they married in a church, the recent register may still be at the church, and some churches may allow you to search the register (may be for a fee).

If you are not able to access GRO records, you might consider looking in the local newspaper archives. Many weddings may have be recorded there.

Comment: If you're looking for only one or two records, an alternative to hiring a genealogist is to call upon one of the volunteers at Random Acts of Genealogical Kindness (RAOGK). For example, there is at least [one](https://raogk.org/lookups/?wpbdp_view=search&kw=Birmingham) based in Birmingham who offers to help with UK BMD lookups.

Comment: Clarification - this answer applies to England and Wales only - which is sort of implied if you understand the organisational names. Scotland and Northern Ireland each have their own system.

Comment: @AdrianB38 Good point - I'll edit to clarify. I assumed the question was referring to England and Wales as it referenced online indexes up to 2005, while Scotland's indexes are online up to much more recently, not sure about NI.